# CefSharp Spell Checker not working on certain PCs

Tags: cefsharp

At first, I thought it was a network issue **as there is some added security on the machines**.
Spellchecking on Chrome is working though.

Then, I thought maybe it doesn't detect the current Locale correctly.
I set the Locale to "el" (Greek) in CefSettings, I see that this take effect as the context menu is changed to Greek, but spell checking still doesn't work.

Are there any Network/Security/Environment settings that could affect this?

I can reproduce this on the latest version of CefSharp(94.4.5) using [the minimal example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample).
I just navigate to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea and type some text.

As I said, the same app works on most PCs

Comment: Have you checked the log file? The dictionary is download at runtime, if the download fails then you won't get spell checking. The dictionary location is http://cefsharp.github.io/api/94.4.x/html/P_CefSharp_CefSettingsBase_UserDataPath.htm try compare the folder contents of a working machine to a non working

Comment: Thanks @amaitland, I'll get back to you tomorrow